# How can i get Account id in Lead object for Formula

Tags: formula, account, leads

Firstly i need the write query in mailchimp entegration for salesforce contacts and leads, in this case i will get 1 checkbox situation. with formula but in leads i dont have lookup for account rather i have but any times its coming null but i saw one thing, if my leads have account i can see like this.
**Here to Lead under account object,**
[image: Accounts]
in this case can i get account field ? with formula or without just i need the get and actually i dont wanna write apex update code because too many records have and i cant use 2000 up OFFSET.

Comment: there is a field on lead `ConvertedAccountId` this field is populated with AccountId when the lead is converted. Similarly, we have fields for Contact and Opportunity as well.

Comment: how can i find this fields I know its possible because already PageBlock Have about Account but and how can i search this problem,

Comment: you can refer this field in formula field of lead or even query on lead

Comment: Can write for example please because i couldnt see reference account field just i have Pageblock Account how can i add in my formula ?

Answer (score 0):

There are fields for converted records on the lead object. Which are not visible on the layout but you can use them in the formula or SOQL.

Here are those fields

Account - `ConvertedAccountId`
Contact - `ConvertedContactId`
Opportunity - `ConvertedOpportunityId`

In the Advanced formula editor, you can find those fields.
[image]

Sample Query

```
SELECT Id, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, ConvertedOpportunityId FROM Lead
```

Comment: Hi i run the my query and result this: https://ibb.co/WyBdB9N

Comment: I guess we cant see account object in formula thats why i need to do update for all lead records but its not healhtly all of this for mailchimp query The records I want do not come

Comment: @FurkanKuyular if the lead is not converted to Account, you won't get ant AccountId in the Query.